# How can I move folders inside themselves with an additional string?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, find, move

I'm doing more spring cleaning.

I have a folder structure like the following:

```
AAA
  |____ BLA
         |____ 2020-123
                      |____bunchoffiles 
BBB
  |____ XYZ
         |____ 2020-124
                      |____bunchoffiles 
CCC
  |____ QWE
         |____ 2020-125
                      |____bunchoffiles
```

I want to create a subfolder inside these folders using a string in their path like:

If the path contains AAA, BBB, CCC etc.  i have to create that sub folder under the folder name, and move its contents inside that subfolder. The purpose for this is i want to move them to a new destination, grouped (OCD bells are ringing). To be more clear:

```
DESTINATION
          |__________2020-123 
                            |____ AAA
                                    |____bunchoffiles 
DESTINATION
          |__________2020-124 
                            |____ BBB
                                    |____bunchoffiles 
DESTINATION
          |__________2020-125 
                            |____ CCC
                                    |____bunchoffiles
```

So the pseudo-code is like:

```
1. Get the full path of each folder
2. Search for a string
3. If found (it will be) create a new folder under that folder with that string
4. Move the files under the original folder to the newly created folder
```

What i tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash          
STR=$(pwd)
SUB='AAA'
STR2=$(pwd)  | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'



if grep -q "$SUB" <<< "$STR"; then

for f in *; do
if [ -d "$f" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$f/$SUB"
    mv "$f/*" "$f/$SUB/"
fi
done

fi
```

Fails.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Intall `vidir` and try to edit it the path yourself, and may the force be with you, good luck!

Comment: something like `shopt -s globstar` and `vidir ./???/**` the three `?` will match three strings and `globstar` will/should force `vidir` to decend inyour directory path.

Comment: If you wan to use your favorite editor try `EDITOR=my_favorite_editor vidir ./???/**` provided you have `globstar` enabled the `???` is the path which should match your `AAA` ,`BBB` and `CCC`

Comment: @KaanGunduz : (1) For the code you have written already, please [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (2) _try to edit the folders.txt file_  - What do you mean by this? You did not mention a file of this name before in the question, and what do you mean that you **tried** to edit it? You haven't been successful in editing? Did you check whether the file maybe is write protected?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash          
STR=$(pwd)
SUB='AAA'
STR2=$(pwd)  | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'



if grep -q "$SUB" <<< "$STR"; then

for f in *; do
if [ -d "$f" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$f/$SUB"
    mv "$f"/* "$f"/"$SUB"/
fi
done

fi
```

The only error i got was in the mv line, i forgot to remove /* from inside quotes. Thanks Obi Wan Kenobi.